# How can I fix the ugly fonts in java applications?

Tags: 11.04, java

In Natty, and maybe since Ubuntu is using the ambiance theme by default, it seems java applications have a problem with fonts.

This screen is easily reproducible by starting [this webstart application](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/jws/SwingSet2.jnlp) and selecting the GTK look and feel.

The only exception is Eclipse which shows perfectly standard menu and fonts. Every other java application using ambiance through the GTK style shows this ugly rendering.

Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR : You can't.

Eclipse uses swt which uses your native font rendering libraries and pretty much everything else uses Swing which does not.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found was changing "Application font" from Ubuntu/11 to Sans/10.
BTW: For me, sans looks better than default ubuntu.